# after transform, xslt to add default value where xml element doesn't exist

Tags: xslt

I'm struggling  to test to see if an element exists. If it doesn't, I'd like to add in a default value. Here's my XML:

```
<Transaction>
 <InvoicePeriod>1</InvoicePeriod>
 <Product>Shoe</Product>
</Transaction>
```

If InvoicePeriod element doesnt exist, default should be 1 :

```
<Transaction>
 <Product>Shoe</Product>
</Transaction>
```

Here is my XSLT. "InvoicePeriod" is supposed to transform into "invoiceP" in a generic format (it works), but how to fit in this when you write code to change default if InvoicePeriod element doesnt exist:

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction" >
  <Transaction invoiceP="{InvoicePeriod}" >
  <xsl:sequence select="concat($InvoicePeriod, '1'[not($InvoicePeriod)])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<Transaction>
 <InvoiceP>1</InvoiceP>
 <Product>Shoe</Product>
</Transaction>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is. What do you mean by *"how to fit in this when you write code to change default"*? I would go for an `xsl:if` or even an `xsl:choose` over what you have written, but either way works. What help do you need?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. Yes i tried xsl:choose and xsl:when. Look here:  <xsl:attribute name="invoiceP">
    <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@InvoicePeriod and (@InvoicePeriod!='') and (@InvoicePeriod!='0')">
   <xsl:value-of select="@InvoicePeriod"/></xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
it is not working when xml element doesnt exist that change to default '1'

Comment: Your xsl:when seem to be OK. Only InvoicePeriod is an  node name not an attribute in your example. Therfor remove all `@` before  InvoicePeriod and it should do. `<xsl:when test="InvoicePeriod and (InvoicePeriod!='') and (InvoicePeriod!='0')">
      <xsl:value-of select="InvoicePeriod"/>
     </xsl:when>`

Comment: @hr_117 thanks it is working but one problem is that when value is 2 or any number, it keeps return to default 1.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, this should not happen with above xsl:when,or  with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="def_InvoicePeriod" select="'1'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="InvoicePeriod" >
        <invoiceP>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </invoiceP>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Transaction[not(InvoicePeriod)]" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <invoiceP>
                <xsl:value-of select="$def_InvoicePeriod"/>
            </invoiceP>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

def_InvoicePeriod could be changed  while calling your transformation.
E.g wiht xslptorc:

```
xsltproc --stringparam def_InvoicePeriod 2  xsltfile xmlfile
```

Update: (It seems invoiceP should be an attribute in Transaction and the default value should be use also for empty value or value="0".

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param  name="def_InvoicePeriod" select="'1'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="InvoicePeriod" />
    <xsl:template match="Transaction" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="invoiceP">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="number(InvoicePeriod) &gt; '0' ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="InvoicePeriod"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$def_InvoicePeriod"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update Test input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <Transaction>
        <InvoicePeriod>1</InvoicePeriod>
        <Product>Shoe</Product>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <InvoicePeriod>3</InvoicePeriod>
        <Product>Shoe1</Product>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <InvoicePeriod>0</InvoicePeriod>
        <Product>Shoe2</Product>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <Product>Shoe3</Product>
    </Transaction>
</xml>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xnl>
  <Transaction invoiceP="1">
    <Product>Shoe</Product>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction invoiceP="3">
    <Product>Shoe1</Product>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction invoiceP="1">
    <Product>Shoe2</Product>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction invoiceP="1">
    <Product>Shoe3</Product>
  </Transaction>
</xnl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking something like:

```
  <xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <Transaction>
      <xsl:if test="not(InvoicePeriod)">
        <InvoiceP>1</InvoiceP>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Transaction>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code (that you showed in the comment) is that you're looking at `@InvoicePeriod` which is an *attribute* of `Transaction` which never appears. You need to check simply `InvoicePeriod` which is the child element of that name.

If you actually need the Invoice Period as an attribute `InvoiceP` then you need something like this. I've also copied the `Product` element as I didn't know what else to do with it.

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="InvoiceP">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="InvoicePeriod and InvoicePeriod > 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="InvoicePeriod"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**output**

```
 <Transaction InvoiceP="1">
     <Product>Shoe</Product>
 </Transaction>
```